# Header file missing when compiling HHVM Extension

Tags: php, c++, hhvm

I found this gearman extension for HHVM here https://github.com/longlong2010/hhvm-gearman and thought to give it a try, now when I try to build it for HHVM but I get this error.

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/hhvm/extension-gearman$ cmake . && make
-- Configuring for HHVM API version 20150212
-- gearman Include dir: /usr/include/libgearman
-- libgearman library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgearman.so
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/vagrant/hhvm/extension-gearman
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/gearman.dir/gearman.cpp.o
/home/vagrant/hhvm/extension-gearman/gearman.cpp:17:45: fatal error: hphp/runtime/base/base-includes.h: No such file or directory
 #include "hphp/runtime/base/base-includes.h"
                                             ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/gearman.dir/gearman.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/gearman.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**Content of my config.cmake file is**

```
FIND_PATH(GEARMAN_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES gearman.h 
    PATHS /usr/include/libgearman /usr/local/include/libgearman)

FIND_LIBRARY(GEARMAN_LIBRARY NAMES gearman PATHS /usr/lib /usr/local/lib)

IF (GEARMAN_INCLUDE_DIR)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "gearman Include dir: ${GEARMAN_INCLUDE_DIR}")
    MESSAGE(STATUS "libgearman library: ${GEARMAN_LIBRARY}")
ELSE()
    MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Cannot find libgearman library")
ENDIF()

include_directories(${GEARMAN_INCLUDE_DIR})


HHVM_EXTENSION(gearman gearman.cpp)
HHVM_SYSTEMLIB(gearman ext_gearman.php)

target_link_libraries(gearman ${GEARMAN_LIBRARY})
```

*****EDIT******
I fixed the above issue by replacing hphp/runtime/base/base-includes.h with hphp/runtime/ext/extension.h

but Now I get this error during compilation process

```
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/gearman.dir/gearman.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/include/hphp/runtime/ext/extension.h:23:0,
                 from /home/vagrant/hhvm/extension-gearman/gearman.cpp:18:
/usr/include/hphp/runtime/vm/native.h: In instantiation of ‘void HPHP::Native::registerBuiltinFunction(const char*, Fun) [with Fun = bool (*)(HPHP::ObjectData*, HPHP::String&)]’:
/home/vagrant/hhvm/extension-gearman/gearman.cpp:351:4:   required from here
/usr/include/hphp/runtime/vm/native.h:368:3: error: static assertion failed: Arguments on builtin function were not understood types
   static_assert(
   ^
/usr/include/hphp/runtime/vm/native.h: In instantiation of ‘void HPHP::Native::registerBuiltinFunction(const char*, Fun) [with Fun = bool (*)(HPHP::ObjectData*, HPHP::String&, long int)]’:
/home/vagrant/hhvm/extension-gearman/gearman.cpp:360:4:   required from here
/usr/include/hphp/runtime/vm/native.h:368:3: error: static assertion failed: Arguments on builtin function were not understood types
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/gearman.dir/gearman.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/gearman.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
ta*, HPHP::String&, long int)]’:
/home/vagrant/hhvm/extension-gearman/gearman.cpp:360:4:   required from here
/usr/include/hphp/runtime/vm/native.h:368:3: error: static assertion failed: Arguments on builtin function were not understood types
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/gearman.dir/gearman.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/gearman.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed it myself,  in new version of HHVM 3.6 and 3.7 functions passed should be pointers String constants not just String I just had to replace this

```
bool HHVM_METHOD(GearmanWorker, addServer, String& host, int64_t port) {...
```

with this

```
bool HHVM_METHOD(GearmanWorker, addServer, const String& host, int64_t port) {...
```